# Plot predicted probabilities and confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval

This is a plot I did, I want the confidence intervals for the plot, both upper and lower. I have come so far that I have produced both the upper and lower range but I have problems with the plot that includes the confidence interval.

Here are a few lines of my data, gdk is my binary response and the second variable is the age

```
               gdk    age prog      calender
29            FALSE    59 NASTK       11
30            FALSE    59 NASTK       10
91             TRUE    49 NMATK        9
129            TRUE    47 NFYSK        8
227           FALSE    46 LARAA       13
244            TRUE    44 LARAA       11
256            TRUE    41 LARAA        9
311           FALSE    38 NMATK        7
323           FALSE    42 NSFYY       11
393            TRUE    40 LARAA       11
449           FALSE    37 NSFYY        9
450           FALSE    38 NSFYY       10
```

This is the code for my first plot:

```
prop<-numeric()
for (i in 18:60){prop[i-17]<-mean(both$gdk[both$age==i],na.rm=TRUE)}

mod.red.fin<-glm(respons ~prog+age+calender, family=binomial,data=both)
newdata<-data.frame(prog="NMATK",calender=7, age=18:60)
plot(18:60, predict(mod.red.fin, newdata, type="respons"))
```

[image]

to bring up my confidence, I used the code:

```
newdata<-data.frame(prog="NMATK",calender=7, age=18:60)
newdata2<-cbind(newdata, predict(mod.red.fin, newdata, type="link", se=TRUE))
newdata2<-within(newdata2, {PredictedProb<-plogis(fit)
                            LL<-plogis(fit-(1.96*se.fit))
                            UL<-plogis(fit+(1.96*se.fit))})

head(newdata2)
   prog    calender age    fit    se.fit  residual.scale        UL        LL   PredictedProb
1 NMATK        7    18 1.637162 0.2128354              1 0.8863833 0.7720644     0.8371484
2 NMATK        7    19 1.569661 0.2072370              1 0.8782376 0.7619639     0.8277353
3 NMATK        7    20 1.502160 0.2032196              1 0.8699448 0.7509808     0.8178965
4 NMATK        7    21 1.434660 0.2008779              1 0.8615687 0.7390311     0.8076263
5 NMATK        7    22 1.367159 0.2002708              1 0.8531708 0.7260410     0.7969207
6 NMATK        7    23 1.299658 0.2014139              1 0.8448057 0.7119527     0.7857774
```

**how do I then plot the confidence interval? Need help with the code.
checked a bit on the `library(ggplot2)` but did not come up with anything.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ggplot` (probably the easiest way to create your desired plots), use the `stat_smooth()` geom.

However, you have a problem with your desired plot. You can only have 1 *x* variable plotted at a time with `ggplot`. That being said, here's some example code that should get you stated:

```
d = read.table(header = TRUE, text =          
"              gdk    age prog      calender
             FALSE    59 NASTK       11
             FALSE    59 NASTK       10
              TRUE    49 NMATK        9
              TRUE    47 NFYSK        8
             FALSE    46 LARAA       13
              TRUE    44 LARAA       11
              TRUE    41 LARAA        9
             FALSE    38 NMATK        7
             FALSE    42 NSFYY       11
              TRUE    40 LARAA       11
             FALSE    37 NSFYY        9
             FALSE    38 NSFYY       10")
## Convert gkk from T/F to 1/0
d$gdk2 <- as.numeric(d$gdk)
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = age, y = gdk2)) + 
            stat_smooth(method = 'glm', family = 'binomial') +
            theme_bw()

ggsave('plot1.jpg', plot1, width = 6, height = 4)
```

Which gives you this plot:
[image]

plot2 <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = calender, y = gdk2)) + 
        stat_smooth(method = 'glm', family = 'binomial') +
        theme_bw()

```
ggsave('plot2.jpg', plot2, width = 6, height = 4)
```

Which gives you this figure.[image]

BTW, I know `ggplot2` can be hard to learn. I would suggest checking out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2/info) for more information. 
Also, the first Google hit for "confidence ggplot2" was the offical [`ggplot2` documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_smooth.html) for plotting confidence intervals.

Comment: You're welcome. Did my answer get all of you question? If not, what else would you like to do? If so, would you please mark the question as solved.