# How to plot predicted probabilities from a GLM with 2-column matrix response?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, predict

I would like to plot the regression line from a glm model (written below). Ideally I'd like to plot it over the observed data, but I haven't been able to adapt the code I've found elsewhere (e.g. [predict.glm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/predict.glm), [Plot predicted probabilities and confidence intervals in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002535/plot-predicted-probabilities-and-confidence-intervals-in-r)).

Here is a subset of the data :

```
     Pos   Tot   Age
    <int> <int> <int>
1     1    11     1
2     0     1     1
3     3     3     1
4     1     2     1
5     5     7     1
47   13    16     4
48    9     9     4
49    9    10     4
50   14    14     4    
158   1     3     2
159   3     5     2
160   0     7     2
161   9    12     2
162   0     2     2
209   0     1     3
210   1     2     3
211   1     1     3
212   2     2     3
```

Each row represents a unique location. I removed location column to de-identify.

Here is my model:

```
 model1 <- glm(cbind(Tot - Pos, Pos) ~ -1+Age,
            family = binomial(link = "log"), data = data.frame)
```

My goal is to plot the predicted probabilities of different glm models for visual comparison...but for now I can't even figure out how to plot my simplest model.

**Edit**
Because the response is a two-column matrix, I don't think there is a way to graph in ggplot. Can someone confirm?

I had tried to plot in ggplot, but due to the model response being a two-column matrix, the aesthetics of the plot and of the model did not match:

```
ggplot(data.frame, aes(x = Age, y = Pos/Tot)) +
geom_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0.05) +
geom_smooth(method = glm, formula = cbind(Tot-Pos, Pos) ~ -1+Age, se = FALSE)
```

which returns a scatter plot of the observed values but also gives me the error message:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
object 'Tot' not found
```

So I'm now trying to figure out how to plot using the `predict` function, which I've never done before.

This is what I have so far, adapting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002535/plot-predicted-probabilities-and-confidence-intervals-in-r):

```
 newdata<-data.frame(Age = 1:4)
 plot(1:4, predict(model1, newdata, type="link"))
```

How do I add 95% confidence intervals and transform the data back to a probability scale of 0-1 on the y-axis?

Thanks very much

Comment: Formula edited.

Comment: See [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html)

Comment: It can be possible to use `stat_smooth`, but the straightforward way is to use the `predict` function to generate a data frame of probabilities, and then plot it as you would any other data frame.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your best attempt with ggplot - it would let us know where your confusion is to help you learn what needs fixing.

Comment: @Gregor best ggplot attempt added to my question.

Comment: 'formula' argument added thanks to @A.Suliman link.

Comment: Ah - thanks for adding your attempt. Simple mistake, in the `geom_smooth` formula you need to use the aesthetic names not the column names. Change it to `formula = y ~ x - 1` and it should work fine.

Comment: @Gregor I see. However, my formula does not contain a response vector of the form `y ~ x`, but rather the response is a two-column matrix (defined in my formula as `cbind(Tot-Pos, Pos)` [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/glm) . I think this matrix is the crux of my plotting issues. How do I plot glm prediction probabilities when the response is a two-column matrix? (maybe I should edit the title of the question?)

Comment: Ah, I see. Editing your question title and body to make the crux of the issue clear would be good, but my guess is there isn't a way to do it inside `stat_smooth`. `ggplot` is a plotting package that happens to have a lightweight interface to modeling functions, but when things get complex is usually best to do your fitting and predicting separately from your plotting. I'd again recommend just using the straightforward approach of just using the `predict` function to generate a data frame with predictions.

Comment: @Gregor thanks for your help. I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to generate the predictions:

```
pd = data.frame(Age = 1:4)

# use type = "response" for probability-scale predictions    
preds = predict(model1, newdata = pd, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)
pd$fit = preds$fit
pd$se = preds$se.fit
```

And then plot:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x = Age, y = Pos / Tot)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0.05)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = pd, aes(y = fit, ymin = fit - 1.96 * se, ymax = fit + 1.96 * se),
              fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(data = pd, aes(y = fit))
```

[image]

From the plot, we can see that the model and plot are somewhat contradictory - this is because your model is specified as predicting the probability `(Tot - Pos) / Pos`, but your plot is showing the complement `Pos / Tot`, I'd recommend changing one to match the other.

---

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Pos   Tot   Age
1     1    11     1
2     0     1     1
3     3     3     1
4     1     2     1
5     5     7     1
47   13    16     4
48    9     9     4
49    9    10     4
50   14    14     4    
158   1     3     2
159   3     5     2
160   0     7     2
161   9    12     2
162   0     2     2
209   0     1     3
210   1     2     3
211   1     1     3
212   2     2     3")
```

And the model from your question:

```
model1 <- glm(cbind(Tot - Pos, Pos) ~ -1+Age,
        family = binomial(link = "log"), data = dd)
```